# Links to a contribution page with checksum and contact ID generate a fatal error

Tags: wordpress, checksum

I want to send email to members with a link to the membership renewal page profiled with their data. I create a suitable link including the contact ID and checksum, of the form

https://example.com/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2&cid=xxx&cs=1ccf75cf22138bd255525af8c8c05dc4_1599646931_168

If I'm logged and the link is for me then it works. If I'm not logged a Fatal Error is generated, and the site (WP) presents the message "The site is experiencing technical difficulties".

Nothing appears in the CiviCRM log, but in the Apache log I see:

> Sep 09 13:56:02 [Wed Sep 09 12:56:02.301893 2020] [php7:error] [pid
> 203] [client 172.18.0.1:41254] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught
> CRM_Core_Exception: [0: One of parameters (value: ) is not of the type
> Integer\n\n thrown in
> /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Type.php on
> line 470 Sep 09 13:56:02 172.18.0.1 - - [09/Sep/2020:12:56:01 +0000]
> "GET
> /civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2&cid=213&cs=1ccf75cf22138bd255525af8c8c05dc4_1599646931_168
> HTTP/1.1" 500 3081 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15;
> rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0"

Using Civi 5.29 with WP 5.21. I had the same problem using Civi 5.25.0. I'm using a Cloudron LAMP stack, which makes things a little more complicated.

Any pointers most welcome.

Comment: Not an answer as such, but for the front-end, use `civiwp=CiviCRM` rather than `page=CiviCRM`. Also, I'd recommend using Clean URLs. I'll follow up if that makes no difference.

Comment: if that helps i think it should be added as an Answer

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that out.

Comment: Update. Nope:using civiwp=CiviCRM makes no difference. And clean URLs doesn't work either - that's where I'd started. If I remove the query string elements containing the contact Id and checksum I can reach the page fine (with clean URLS, with page= and with civiwp=). The problem seems to be with how Civi is handling the query

Comment: What happens if you remove the `&reset=1` part? The URLs that work for me don't have that - I used the Contact Checksum UI extension to generate them FWIW https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-checksum-ui

Comment: Makes no difference. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that anonymous users are not able to view and use contribution pages.
Confirm and change this at:

Administer->Users and Permissions->Permissions (Access Control)->Wordpress Access Control.

OR

https://yoursite.tld/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Faccess%2Fwp-permissions&reset=1

Comment: A reasonable suggestion, but not relevant in this case. If I point my browser to the contribution page address without the query string containing contact ID and checksum, the page renders fine whether I'm logged in or not.